# A simple view CANNOT align to bottom to ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

[UPDATE1]

The `layout` tag is for dataBinding purpose. I tried remove `layout` and let ConstraintLayout as root container, the issue is still there, thanks.

I want to simply make a view align in the bottom of a contraintLayout, but I always got a margin/gap between the view and bottom side.

Here is the code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp">

        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And what look like on device is
[image: img]

However, if I replace the ContraintLayout with FrameLayout, everything is file.

Here is the code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And what it looks like(No extra space between button and parent's bottom):
[image: img]

I have struggled in this problem at least 7~8hours, and still have no idea what happened. Does any one has some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need the parent layout (which doesn't even have a closing tag)? It's propably better to put the xmlns:android and xmlns:app directly into the ConstraintLayout. That looks like a really cool device by the way. ;-) What is that thing? Does it work on the emulator?

Comment: Use the Layout Inspector to try to find out what is going on. In Android Studio it's Tools->Layout Inspector then choose your app.

Comment: @qwerty I use dataBinding in my project that's why you see parent <layout>. This device has physical buttons and infrared scanner. It works fine on the emulator.

Comment: If the app has to run only on this device you could try using negative margin/padding.

Comment: Unfortunately, this app runs on many different devices, some has physical buttons, others are not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use `layout` tag in your xml.

Put this in your xml file instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Whether or not there is `layout` tag as parent (I'm using dataBinding in this project), the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Simply remove `<layout>` tag from xml file doesn't take any effect.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I found the root cause coming from ConstraintLayout library.

For version 1.1.3, everything is fine.
`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

However when I upgrade version to 2.0.0-beta2, this strange behavior was happened.
`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'`

I should use stable release only, thanks all.